# Литература по изучению cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, книги, cocos2d

Когда я заинтересовалась кокосом, я заметила, что нормальную и полную информацию практически не возможно найти. Я читала документацию, но мне этого кажется мало. Если кто-то знает норм книгу или еще какую-либо инфу, прошу со мной поделиться.

Comment: Все так. С документацией, а тем более с литературой печаль. Часто приходиться в тесты/примеры лезть, благо, что опенсурс. В этом плане мармалад чуть лучше задокументирован, но там варианты с лицензией более сердитые.

Comment: список литературы следует указывать в [описании метки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/cocos2d/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Как по мне самая лучшая книга](https://www.packtpub.com/game-development/cocos2d-x-cookbook/?utm_source=GC-cocos2d-x.org&utm_medium=pod&utm_campaign=1783284757) в ней охватывается множество примеров использования функций движка, не просто разработка какой то конкретной игры, а именно как работать с теми или иными возможностями, к примеру как работать с sql, или как правильно создавать интерфейс, т.е. данная книга не загоняет вас в рамки какой то конкретной игры

Comment: список литературы следует указывать в [описании метки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/cocos2d/info)

Answer (score 1):

Cocos2d-x-Game Development Essentials - норм книга, но есть темные места
еще норм Raydelto Hernandez  Building Android Games with Cocos2d-x, но советую сначала первую прочитать

Comment: список литературы следует указывать в [описании метки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/cocos2d/info)